# Map size greater than allocated memory

Tags: java, memory, dictionary, size, out-of-memory

I have a 8GB memory. I set the java heap size using

```
-Xmx7000m
```

Say, I have a 12 GB file as input. I read the file and put every word in a map where the value for every key is the frequency of the word. Under the assumption that most of words will be unique, will the map size grow greater than the size of my memory that I have allocated?

If not, what could be the possible reason behind this error?

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.assignment2.WordCountJ.startCounting(WordCountJ.java:63)
    at com.test.assignment2.WordCountJ.prepareToCount(WordCountJ.java:35)
    at com.test.assignment2.WordCountJ.run(WordCountJ.java:23)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You could find out for sure by using a memory profiler. However, it seems that you already have a fairly good grasp of the problem.

Comment: You're wondering if 12GB will fit in 7GB?  Isn't that sort of self-explanatory?

Comment: @Jeff My question was something like - every char would occupy 2 bytes even in a Collection or the object would occupy lesser space as a whole?

Comment: I'm fairly certain the objects actually occupy MORE space, though I have no sources to back up that claim at the moment.  But there's much more information associated with a `String` object than just a collection of characters.